# When trying to use Keras to build a model to be trained with distributed tensorflow I get RuntimeError: Graph is finalized and cannot be modified

Tags: tensorflow, keras, distributed

So I'm trying to adapt the distributed tensorflow examples to work with Keras. I'm not sure this is entirely possible but I figured I would give it a try. Here is my script to start the workers

```
import tensorflow as tf
import keras
from keras import backend as K
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, InputLayer
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.datasets import mnist

def get_data():
    (x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()

    num_classes = 10
    x_train = x_train.reshape(60000, 784)
    x_test = x_test.reshape(10000, 784)
    x_train = x_train.astype('float32')
    x_test = x_test.astype('float32')
    x_train /= 255
    x_test /= 255

    # convert class vectors to binary class matrices
    y_train = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_train, num_classes)
    y_test = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_test, num_classes)

    return x_train, y_train

tf.app.flags.DEFINE_string("ps_hosts", "", "List of parameter server addresses'")
tf.app.flags.DEFINE_string("worker_hosts", "", "List of worker addresses'")
tf.app.flags.DEFINE_integer("task_index", "", "Index of task within the job")
FLAGS = tf.app.flags.FLAGS

task_index = FLAGS.task_index
ps_hosts = FLAGS.ps_hosts.split(",")
worker_hosts = FLAGS.worker_hosts.split(",")

cluster_spec = tf.train.ClusterSpec({'ps' : ps_hosts, 'worker' : worker_hosts})

server = tf.train.Server(cluster_spec, job_name='worker', task_index=task_index)

worker_device = 'job:worker/task:{}'.format(task_index)

replica_device = tf.train.replica_device_setter(
    worker_device = worker_device, 
    cluster = cluster_spec)

x_train, y_train = get_data()

with tf.device(replica_device):
    K.manual_variable_initialization(True)

    global_step = tf.get_variable(name='global_step', shape=[], 
        initializer=tf.constant_initializer(0), trainable=False)

    init_op = tf.global_variables_initializer() 
    supervisor = tf.train.Supervisor(is_chief=(task_index == 0), 
        global_step=global_step, init_op=init_op)
    sess = supervisor.prepare_or_wait_for_session(server.target)

    K.set_session(sess)

    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(512, activation='relu', input_shape=(784,)))
    model.add(Dropout(0.2))
    model.add(Dense(512, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(10, activation='softmax'))
    model.compile(optimizer='sgd', loss='categorical_crossentropy')


    model.fit(x_train[:1000], y_train[:1000], epochs=1)
```

Here is my script to start the parameter server

```
import tensorflow as tf

if __name__ == '__main__':
    tf.app.flags.DEFINE_string("ps_hosts", "", "List of parameter server addresses'")
    tf.app.flags.DEFINE_string("worker_hosts", "", "List of worker addresses'")
    tf.app.flags.DEFINE_integer("task_index", 0, "Index of task within the job")

FLAGS = tf.app.flags.FLAGS

task_index = FLAGS.task_index
ps_hosts = FLAGS.ps_hosts.split(",")
worker_hosts = FLAGS.worker_hosts.split(",")
cluster = { 'ps' : ps_hosts, 'worker' : worker_hosts }

cluster = {"ps" : ps_hosts, "worker" : worker_hosts}
server = tf.train.Server(cluster, job_name='ps', task_index=task_index)
server.join()
```

Here is my script to run these processes

```
#!/bin/bash
python3 start_ps.py --job_name=ps --ps_hosts=localhost:2222 --worker_hosts=localhost:2223,localhost:2224 --task_index=0 &
python3 start_worker.py --ps_hosts=localhost:2222 --worker_hosts=localhost:2223,localhost:2224 --task_index=0 &
python3 start_worker.py --ps_hosts=localhost:2222 --worker_hosts=localhost:2223,localhost:2224 --task_index=1
```

When I run this I am getting the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "start_worker.py", line 62, in <module>
    model.add(Dense(512, activation='relu', input_shape=(784,)))
  File "/Users/user/projects/keras/keras/models.py", line 421, in add
    dtype=layer.dtype, name=layer.name + '_input')
  File "/Users/user/projects/keras/keras/engine/topology.py", line 1375, in Input
    input_tensor=tensor)
  File "/Users/pzx496/projects/keras/keras/engine/topology.py", line 1286, in __init__
    name=self.name)
  File "/Users/pzx496/projects/keras/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py", line 349, in placeholder
    x = tf.placeholder(dtype, shape=shape, name=name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/array_ops.py", line 1530, in placeholder
    return gen_array_ops._placeholder(dtype=dtype, shape=shape, name=name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/gen_array_ops.py", line 1954, in _placeholder
    name=name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/op_def_library.py", line 767, in apply_op
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2458, in create_op
    self._check_not_finalized()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2181, in _check_not_finalized
    raise RuntimeError("Graph is finalized and cannot be modified.")
RuntimeError: Graph is finalized and cannot be modified.
```

I thought by setting K.manual_variable_initialization(True) Keras would not initialize vars until I told it too. This appears to not be the case. Any idea how I can fix this behavior?

Comment: Shouldn't variables be initialized after model definition?

Comment: @MarcinMożejko I've been trying to adapt the examples I've seen using distributed tensorflow https://github.com/jjasonn0717/Distributed-Mnist/blob/master/distributed_mnist.py. In all the examples the init op is taken care of by a Supervisor object. I thought it made the most sense to not have Keras initialize vars on its own.